# Facebook sdk.js returns 404 error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My web-app has the Facebook JS SDK implemented.

Yesterday, everything was working fine and without any modification on the code, the script request started to return 404 errors.

[image: Facebook SDK 404 request error shown in browser dev tools.]

When I try to access it directly, this is what I find:

[image: Screenshot of sdk.js in the browser, which is just a white page with the text "Not Found".]

Facebook Status shows that the API everything is OK.

[image: Screenshot of Facebook status dashboard that shows everything as healthy with no issues.]

Instagram's embeds.js and Facebook's debug SDK are also returning the same error:

[image: Screenshot of Instagram's embeds.js in the browser. The page simply says, "Not Found".]

[image: Screenshot of Facebook's debug.js in the browser. The page simply says, "Not Found".]

Does anyone knows what it happening? I've tried accessing these files using my 4G network and the same error is displayed.

I'm based in Dublin, Ireland.

Comment: If it was working and has now stopped then it's obviously Facebook that has an issue.  What did Facebook say about it when you contacted them?

Comment: i can confirm that this is happening to my apps too.

Comment: Here too on several independent sites.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/219351608476722/

Comment: Update from bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/949091578557056/ : _“We have a fix for this issue and it will be pushed to production immediately; the issue should be resolved in the next few minutes”_

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured this one out.. it seems the .net isn't working anymore.. I used ".com" instead:

Use https://connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js

instead of https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js

Comment: Thank you! Wish we could do the same for Instagram :/

Comment: Well actually the script downloads fine from .com, but it still doesn't work (for my use cases anyway). I see the version tag updating like every few seconds though, so I guess someone is working on fixing whatever is wrong...

Answer (score 5):

It is related to this bug, subscribe to get updated: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/949091578557056/

There is a workaround to use .com instead of .net.

Edit: The bug is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Use //connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js url.