# How to fix "Not Found" Facebook connect script?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

[image: Facebook Not Found]

I'm using this to login Facebook via Javascript and I'm having this 404 error. Has anyone solved this problem?

Edit: Duplicate for [Facebook sdk.js returns 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546695/facebook-sdk-js-404)

Comment: Just don't request the non-existing url?

Comment: This is the URL in the guide from official Facebook docs. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: So, I doubt that this would return a 404 error

Comment: may be a temporary error, just wait or file a bug

Comment: same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546695/facebook-sdk-js-404

Comment: ok, I will post my answer there

Comment: Subscribe to this bug report please https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/949091578557056/

Answer (score 4):

This was working before, but now it seems the .net isn't working anymore. I tried https://connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js instead of https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js and it works now

Answer (score 1):

Someone from the Facebook Team mentioned that a workaround is to change to the URL to: connect.facebook.com instead of connect.facebook.net.

Source:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/949091578557056/