# Can't connect to Facebook SDK.js with error status code 500

Tags: javascript, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm getting a error 500 in the Chrome debugger trying to connect to the Facebook sdk.js file on this line

> fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

in the code here below that was working up to a few minutes ago.
Is there a limit on the number of times I can connecgt in a day or is the server down?

```js
< script >
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '1234',
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v2.8',
      cookie: true
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";

  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); < /script>
```

Comment: It's not down, I can reach https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js

Comment: It was down for our site too. replace connect.facebook.net with connect.facebook.com and it'll work

Comment: It's back up now! Does this frequently go down? I've just started using this in my site!

Comment: Is there any advantage to .com vs .net, I'm just following the directions in the docs from Facebook and they say to use .net the code above is a copy and paste from their site

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546695/facebook-sdk-js-returns-404-error